# PostgreSQL: find rows where a value is equal maximum in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a PostgreSQL that works which uses multiple joins, and one column that is the result of a calculation. From the result of that query I need to extract the rows in which that one column is maximal, and there might be many. If there weren't, I could just `ORDER BY that_column DESC LIMIT 1`; and I found that if I just needed to that on an existing database table, I could just do:

```sql
SELECT columns FROM table_name
WHERE that_coulmn = (SELECT MAX(that_column) FROM table_name)
```

However, that's also not the case. I have a query that is like this:

```
SELECT z.xyz, (x.aa- x.bb) * y.qq as that_column 
FROM table_1 x
JOIN table_2 y ON x.foo = y.foo
JOIN table_3 z ON y.bar = z.bar
JOIN table_4 w ON w.baz = z.baz
where x.aa IS NOT NULL
```

Now, this works. Now I need to know how I put that as a subquery and take from that the `z.xyz` from the rows where `that_column` is maximal. Any help?

Comment: I don't understand. Everything in your queries is right. Did you tried it? Should it work with the knowledge you already had.

Comment: Look at a LATERAL JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is this?

```
SELECT MAX(thatmax.that_column) as theMax FROM (
   SELECT z.xyz, (x.aa- x.bb) * y.qq as that_column 
   FROM table_1 x
   JOIN table_2 y ON x.foo = y.foo
   JOIN table_3 z ON y.bar = z.bar
   JOIN table_4 w ON w.baz = z.baz
   where x.aa IS NOT NULL
) thatmax
```

Comment: That's a good direction, but sadly, this will only get me the max value of thatColumn itself but not more columns of where that max came from.

Comment: @CtrlAltDolev but what columns do you need also? every column from every table?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to select other columns as your output:

```
select * from (
  select *, dense() over(order by (x.aa- x.bb) * y.qq desc) as that_column 
  from table_1 x
  join table_2 y ON x.foo = y.foo
  join table_3 z ON y.bar = z.bar
  join table_4 w ON w.baz = z.baz
  where x.aa IS NOT NULL
) t where that_column = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

I took that as a subquery, used `[rank]`(https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rank-function/) to rank by `thatColumn` and then put that in another subquery to take the ones with rank=1

```
SELECT xyz 
FROM 
    (xyz, thatColumn, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY thatColumn DESC) FROM (
         -- the subquery in the question
    )
) AS highest_and_rank
WHERE thatColumnRank = 1
```

Thank you to everyone who tried to help. You're awesome.

Comment: What is the difference with eshirvana answer? I think it will courtesy give the man some credit or mark it as correct.